# Critical temperature difference between Ising and XY model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, critical-phenomena

The following formula gives the critical coupling (more precisely the ratio of the spin-spin coupling over the temperature) for $O(n)$ models on a triangular lattice:

$$\text{e}^{-2K}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-n}}}$$

with $K=\beta J$

Numerically, it says that:

Ising model (n = 1) has $K \approx 0.27$

XY model (n=2) has $K \approx 0.17$

Thus, the critical temperature for the XY model is higher than the Ising model. I've been thinking about it but I can't come out with a reason of why allowing the order parameter to take continuous values means that we need to go higher in temperature to destroy order. Is there a (semi) intuitive reason for that?

Comment: Your intuition is correct. It is not difficult to prove that the 2-point function of the Ising model is always an upper bound on the corresponding quantity for the XY model. In particular, if $\beta_c^{XY}$ denotes the inverse temperature at which the Kosterlitz-Thouless phase transition occurs, then $\beta_c^{XY}\geq 2\beta_c^{I}$, where $\beta_c^I$ is the inverse critical temperature for the Ising model. You can find the proof [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016%2F0375-9601%2880%2990493-4). Note that the formula you give above is not for the $O(n)$ spin model, but for the $O(n)$ loop model.

Comment: @YvanVelenik: Thanks for confirming my intuition, I'll look more into this inequality. Sorry if it's a foolish question: what's the difference between the spin and the loop models? Aren't the loops just the boundaries between the different spin clusters?

Comment: No, the loop model is an approximation of the O(n) spin model. You can look, for example, at the explanations in Nienhuis' Les Houches lectures on Loop models, which can be downloaded from [his homepage](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~nienhuis/loops.pdf).

Comment: Ok, it's an high-T approximation of the O(n) spin model? Is it still correct near the critical temperature?

It may explain why my O(2) Monte-Carlo simulations (on triangular lattice) are giving me a critical coupling around 0.58 . I haven't been able to find a reference with the right value of the critical coupling on triangular lattice. Would you know of one too? Many thanks for all the help you already gave me.

Comment: ps: In the Ising case, I managed to very precisely check the critical coupling value given by the formula above. That's why it's even more puzzling for me.

Comment: The value of the critical points of the spin and loop models should not be related at all. However, the critical behaviors are expected to be the same (they should belong to the same universality class).

Comment: I have no idea what the value of the coupling constant of the spin O(2) model on the triangular lattice is. There are very efficient cluster methods for this model (as far as I know, I am not a specialist in the numerical aspects) which should provide precise estimates.

Comment: Ok, but so is it a coincidence that the Ising model has same critical coupling for spins and loops or is there some kind of 'self-duality' behind?

Comment: No it's just that for the Ising model, the loop and spin models coincides. This is really due to the fact that the spins take values $\pm 1$, since this implies that $e^{\beta \sigma_i\sigma_j} = \cosh(\beta)(1+\tanh(\beta)\sigma_i\sigma_j)$. (Of course the prefactor $\cosh(\beta)$ in the right-hand side has no impact on the probability distribution.)

Comment: Right, makes sense!